# 'has not been yet extensively studied' vs 'has not been extensively studied yet'

Tags: grammar, word-order

Which of these is correct:

> 'In spite of all that, the effect itself has not been yet extensively studied '

or

> 'In spite of all that, the effect itself has not been extensively studied yet'

Comment: The first one is weak [better is "has not yet been extensively studied"], the second one is better, but better still is to delete the "yet" altogether. It is entirely superfluous.

Comment: I'd tend to say "has not yet been extensively studied."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first sentence is incorrect, because "yet" cannot stand between "been" and the past participle of the verb (in this case, "studied").

The second sentence is not wrong, since "yet" can go last, after "studied," but it still sounds rather clumsy.

I'd suggest "...has not yet been extensively studied." You can, however, delete "yet" entirely without changing the meaning.

Comment: I'd be interested to know of any source you have that clearly states that "yet" cannot stand between "been" and a past participle. Putting it there does indeed create an awkward sentence, IMO, but why "cannot"? Why "incorrect," rather than "less idiomatic" or "clumsier"?